# malloc: *** mmap(size=204800) failed (error code=12)

Tags: ios, memory-management, malloc, mmap, region

I'm writing an application for iPhone and i'm getting the following error :

malloc: *** mmap(size=204800) failed (error code=12)**
 error: can't allocate region
** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I'm getting this after an excessive call of this code :

```
    - (NSInteger) readInt:(NSInteger)defaultValue
{
    NSRange sr = NSMakeRange(offset, [pdfData length] - offset);
    NSData* sub = [pdfData subdataWithRange:sr];
    char* buf = (char*)[sub bytes];
    int off = 0;
    char c;
    do {
        c = buf[off++]; //the app crash on this line 
    } while (c == NEW_LINE || c == CARRIAGE_RETURN||c == EMPTY_STRING);
    int startString = off - 1;
    do {
        c = buf[off++];
    } while (c != NEW_LINE && c != CARRIAGE_RETURN && c !=EMPTY_STRING);
    off = off - 1;
    offset = off + offset+1;

    NSString *inStringSet = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[sub subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(startString, off-startString)] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease]; 
    if ([PDFUtils isNumeric:inStringSet ]) {
        NSString* intString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[sub subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(startString, off-startString)] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease]; 
        return [intString intValue];
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

When running on simulator i don't have such error but i reach about 700mb in memory usage, however when running on a device, the application crash.
I have read similar issues but no luck at all. Any helper pointers will be greatly appreciated. Some issues are talking about finding and debugging leaks but after tracking in Instruments, it appears that there is no leaks and the memory is correctly freed in the auto release pool, there is only memory high peak then its correctly freed. (application only crash in device)
Is there anyway to avoid that peak of memory usage ?
Thanks.